# how to report on date a field was created on?

Tags: administration, metadata, fields

Is there a way (easy) to report on the creation date of each field of each object in Salesforce?

For example, I want to see a list of all the fields for the Account object along with the date the field was created on.

Comment: One easy way I have used in the past is through Workbench, I was sure of the field and it was easy for me to filter down to the field name. Get the Custom field definition using Metadata Types & Components option. I am not sure if there is a metadata report in salesforce unless you write your own using VF page. https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDescribeAndList.php?type=CustomField

Comment: Nothing directly in the app though? Pity, 'must create an idea :-)

Comment: Also you can query the same using REST Explorer tool, one other way I can think of is also to create a field set per object and get the metadata on field set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't give up hope just yet. It might be worth installing the AppExchange app created by Salesforce Labs called the [Object Metadata Snapshot Tool](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Ih3aEAC) that lets you report on Objects and Field metadata.

I haven't verified that Created Date is included in the metadata available for reporting. If it isn't, you can upvote and comment on an already-existing [Salesforce Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpWLAA0). But I hope it's included!

(I don't yet have enough reputation to comment, so I put my comment in this "Answer.")

Comment: Alas, the reports don't appear to include Created Date, Bartley.  Though it is useful for high-level reporting on field metadata such as type, # of digits, help text, formula field expressions, etc.